# SVG rect with fill attribute appears above containing elements inset box shadow

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, css

I have a containing element to my SVG.  This element has an inset box shadow.  Unfortunately when elements go near the sides that have fill they actually get drawn above the box shadow rather than under it.  How can I get around this issue?

[Here is a jsFiddle showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/w6BXs/2/)

HTML:

```html
<div id="holder"></div>​
```

CSS:

```css
#holder {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}​
```

Javascript:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var r = Raphael("holder", 200, 200);

    var rect = r.rect(140, 140, 150, 150);  
    rect.attr({fill:"#fff"});    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have the same problem if instead of having an SVG you would have an image. Fortunately, the workaround for images is well known: apply the box shadow on a pseudo-element that covers the div, example:

```
#holder {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#holder:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VxxwJ/

Answer (score 0):

How about creating another div inside the one with the shadow? Like

```
<div id="holder"><div id="inner"></div></div>​​

#holder {
    box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#inner {
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var r = Raphael("inner");
    var rect = r.rect(140, 140, 70, 70).attr({fill:"#fce"});    
};
```

​
The result looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w6BXs/31/).

Comment: Hi Qnan - That is what I originally did but I would really like the SVG to appear beneath the shadow

Comment: @Chris I doubt that is possible with the css shadow. Maybe a better option is to have it rendered by raphael as well?